# Python can't find submodule in same directory as other submodules it can find

Tags: python, import, module

I have a directory structure along these lines:

```
cops_and_robots/
    __init__.py
    robo_tools/
        __init__.py
        fusion/
            __init__.py
            camera.py
            fusion_engine.py
            gaussian_mixture_model.py
            human.py
            particle_filter.py
            sensor.py
            softmax.py
```

While I can import, say, `sensor.py` easily, I can't import `softmax.py` at all -- it's the one module python doesn't recognize.

Checking for it with `pkgutil` yields the following:

```
import pkgutil
print([name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.walk_packages(['cops_and_robots/robo_tools/fusion']) ])
```

And here's the output:

```
['camera', 'fusion_engine', 'gaussian_mixture_model', 'human', 'particle_filter', 'sensor']
```

Why would one individual submodule not be recognized? What other information could I provide to help debug this?

Comment: is there somthing in `fusion/__init__.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dumb error, but I'm going to keep this around if anyone else has a similar problem:

I had created a backup of my `cops_and_robots` directory on my desktop. Python was trying to import from the local backup, which did not contain the `softmax.py` file, instead of importing the `cops_and_robots` directory on the `PYTHONPATH`.